# Ruby - Insert value in hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, insert

I have this piece of code. I would like to insert a new key-value pair (mine_id, 123456) in the 'details' array for every detail. I am not sure how to do this. Spent about 5 hours trying it out. I am new to Ruby and appreciate all your help.

Thanks again
Regards

```
mineId = "123456"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)
rows = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr")
details = rows.collect do |row|
  detail = {}
  [
    [:prod_year, 'td[1]/font/text()'],
    [:prod_qtr, 'td[2]/font/text()'],
    [:subunit_cd, 'td[3]/font/text()'],
    [:subunit, 'td[4]/font/text()'],
    [:qtr_hrs, 'td[5]/font/text()'],
    [:coal_prod, 'td[6]/font/text()'],
    [:avg_emp_cnt, 'td[7]/font/text()'],
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end
  detail
end
```

Comment: just do `detail[:mineId] = "123456" ; detail`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the key value right before returning details from the block by calling a merge to details hash or explicitly setting the key.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)
rows = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr")
details = rows.collect do |row|
  detail = {}
  [
    [:prod_year, 'td[1]/font/text()'],
    [:prod_qtr, 'td[2]/font/text()'],
    [:subunit_cd, 'td[3]/font/text()'],
    [:subunit, 'td[4]/font/text()'],
    [:qtr_hrs, 'td[5]/font/text()'],
    [:coal_prod, 'td[6]/font/text()'],
    [:avg_emp_cnt, 'td[7]/font/text()'],
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end      
  detail.merge(:mineId => "123456")
end
```

Comment: test5.rb:137:in `merge': wrong number of arguments(2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
        from test5.rb:137:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.rc3-x86-mingw32/
lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `block in each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.rc3-x86-mingw32/
lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `upto'

Comment: I have updated the error in syntax. Instead of , use =>

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)
rows = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr")
details = rows.collect do |row|
  [
    [:prod_year, 'td[1]/font/text()'],
    [:prod_qtr, 'td[2]/font/text()'],
    [:subunit_cd, 'td[3]/font/text()'],
    [:subunit, 'td[4]/font/text()'],
    [:qtr_hrs, 'td[5]/font/text()'],
    [:coal_prod, 'td[6]/font/text()'],
    [:avg_emp_cnt, 'td[7]/font/text()'],
  ].each_with_object({:mineId => 123456}) do |(name, xpath), detail|
    detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end      
end
```

It doesn't matter inside a `Hash`, where the *key/value* exist, as finally you will look for values using the key, so *position* doesn't matter. That's the reason I added, the *key/value* pair(`:mine_id, 123456`) in the first position of the initial argument `Hash` of the `#each_with_object` method.

Comment: Thanks this works. Appreciate your help! As a followup, how can I output this to a csv with the keys as the first row and the values in the subsequent rows? I am using the below code but it is not that elegant since the file is opened multiple times.    rowid = -1
 CSV.open("file.csv", 'a') do |csv|
   details.each do |hsh|
     rowid += 1
     if rowid == 0
       csv << hsh.keys# adding header row (column labels)
     else
       csv << hsh.values
     end# of if/else inside hsh
   end# of hsh's (rows)
 end# of csv open

Comment: @user3830713 separate question please... That I can't answer in *comment*. :-)

Comment: Can post only once every 90 minutes :(

Comment: @user3830713 Why so? Where do you live ?

Comment: US. I am not sure either why it is so!